# Regular expression to replace string after a specific character?

Tags: regex

Actual: Mission_Impossible
Expected: Mission_Accomplished

Comment: do this way https://regex101.com/r/m70Rzn/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to replace whatever follows the `_`?
You can try to use `(?<=_)\w+`, like here in this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VPIQek/2).
It uses a positive look-behind to only match strings following the pattern in the look-behind.

Answer (score 0):

See this :

```
Pattern : [^_]+$

    Match 1
    Full match  27-37   Impossible
    Match 2
    Full match  46-56   Impossible
    Match 3
    Full match  65-75   Impossible
    Match 4
    Full match  84-94   Impossible
    Match 5
    Full match  103-113 Impossible
```

https://regex101.com/r/VPIQek/4